# Proving inequalities in probability theory without Venn diagrams

Tags: probability-theory

I am struggling to prove the following two inequalities without the use and visualization of Venn diagrams.

Given any two events $A$ and $B$, the following is true:

$\mathrm{min}\{\mathbb{P}(A),\mathbb{P}(B)\}\overset{1}{\geq}\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)\overset{2}{\geq}\mathbb{P}(A)+\mathbb{P}(B)-1$

Using Venn diagrams it's trivial to realize that the two inequalities are true, but how should I think in order to formalize it and provide a rigorous proof?

Comment: Try to express what you see in the Venn diagram in words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To begin with, notice that $A\cap B\subset A$ and $A\cap B\subset B$. Therefore
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\textbf{P}(A\cap B) \leq \textbf{P}(A)\\
\textbf{P}(A\cap B) \leq \textbf{P}(B)
\end{cases}\Longrightarrow
\textbf{P}(A\cap B)\leq \min\{\textbf{P}(A),\textbf{P}(B)\}
\end{align*}

On the other hand, we have
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(A\cup B) \leq 1 \Longleftrightarrow \textbf{P}(A) + \textbf{P}(B) - \textbf{P}(A\cap B) \leq 1 \Longleftrightarrow \textbf{P}(A) + \textbf{P}(B) - 1 \leq \textbf{P}(A\cap B)
\end{align*}

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did the trick.

Comment: Is there some result for three events $A,B,C$